# Some contact information not returned by API Get call

Tags: api

I am fetching individual contacts using the following:

```
function get_member($id) {
 $member = array();
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php';
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php';
 $config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton( );
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php';
 $contact = civicrm_api('Contact','Get',array('contact_id' => $id, 'version' =>3));
 if ($contact) {
    $member = $contact['values'][$id];
    $member['membership'] = civicrm_membership_contact_get($id);
 }  
 return $member;
}

function civicrm_membership_contact_get($contact) {
  $params = array('contact_id' => $contact);
  try{
    $result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'get', $params);
    $id = $result['id'];
    return $result['values'][$id];
  } catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getErrorCode();
    $errorData = $e->getExtraParams();
    return array(
      'error' => $errorMessage,
      'error_code' => $errorCode,
      'error_data' => $errorData,
    );
  }

}
```

The values array returned has all of my name fields, address fields, job title, employer, email, region...  but not my website URL.  Screenshot is of the actual contact entry in the Civi admin.

How do I get the Website URL in my data?

[image: admin screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API explorer, the Contact Entity does not return the website information. To include that data, you would have to use a GET action on the Website entity. See the example at (your site)/civicrm/api#examples for the fields the Website entity can return.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  That address is returning 404 on my WordPress Civi install. But I can see the examples at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/examples/Website/Get.php  Seems a bizarre separation.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: What version of Civi do you have? I think as of 4.6 a link to the API explorer is available in the menu under Support > Developer > Explorer. And agreed, it's a weird separation.

Comment: In WP the link would be http://yourdomain/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/api/explorer.

Comment: Thank you guys!  Able to access explorer in the WP install.  That will be very helpful!  Much obliged!